# BrowserCMS portlet

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, content-management-system

This is probably a dumb question, but.. Any ideas how to insert BrowserCMS portlet into an actual page? What is weird, yes, I couldn't find that in their docs....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the section **Adding dynamic content via portlets** in the [BrowserCMS user guide](https://github.com/browsermedia/browsercms/wiki/User%27s-manual)

Click the 'Add Content' button on the container, choose Portlet from the 'types' and then choose the portlet you want.

Answer (score 0):

adding a portlet is not quite intuitive to the beginners -
Once you have created a portlet from your command-line it will be visible in the portlet types when you click on "Add Content", or you can use a pre-designed portlet as well.